# CSS Selectors - Puppeteer - Node.js - how to get classes of element

Tags: node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to download a report from a website.

There is a sidebar that has categories that open up a sub navbar.

I need to check if that category is open or not, I can do this by checking if the category has the class `expanded`.

Meaning the button to open the menu has the selector:

`body > div.main-sidebar > ul.navbar > li:nth-child(5) > h3`

I need to check if that element has the class `.expanded`

When I try

```
 let selector =  page.$(selector2)
 let c = await selector.getProperty("expanded")
```

I get the error that `selector.getProperty is not a function`

How can I check the classes of this element (or a better way to check if the sub navbar is open)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use element handle API, the way is a bit more complicated (and do not forget `await` before the `page.$()`):

```js
const element = await page.$(selector2)
const className = await (await selector.getProperty("className")).jsonValue()
const isOpen = className.split(' ').includes('expanded')
```

So maybe it is simpler to just use a common web API inside `page.evaluate()`:

```js
const isOpen = await page.evaluate(
  selector =>  document.querySelector(selector).matches('.expanded'),
  selector2,
)
```

or:

```js
const isOpen = await page.evaluate(
  selector =>  document.querySelector(selector).classList.contains('expanded')
  selector2,
)
```